# OkHttp Connection reset if connection is enabled

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a use-case that im using mobile internet (via operator), but im over my data limit. In this case my phone sees connection as availabled, but I can't open any webpage.

So in this use-case I receive a SocketException (Connection reset) while trying to make a call with retrofit2 and Okhttp.

In my code app crashes in "return" line:

```
.addInterceptor(Interceptor {
            val newRequest = it.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "${App.sessionManager.tokenType} ${App.sessionManager.accessToken}")
                .build()
            return@Interceptor it.proceed(newRequest)
        })
```

Can someone tell me how to prevent app from a crash? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [Kotlin doesn't force you to `catch` checked exception](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions) – as `SocketException` is – and since no one is catching it the system crashes your application. In Java you'd be forced to catch it.

There's no way to prevent the exception from being thrown – it just means that something unexpected happened – and it would be wrong not to throw it, so you should just `catch` it at some point in your code. Where should you catch it? There's no absolute correct answer to that question, but you should catch it as soon as you can do something useful with it, like logging and re-throwing it or handling it allowing the application's flow continue (e.g., displaying some kind of error to the user and allowing them to retry that operation).

Comment: Yeah, I've added try-catch block where, in case of exception, the "mock response" with code 408 will be created.